# How do I send a bunch of curl commands after publishing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

I'm working on an ASP.net MVC project and I noticed that when the web app gets published, IIS doesn't build a cache or anything for the views until a controller has been hit. So in other words it can take a very long time for a visitor to get the page loaded if they happen to be the first person to visit the page after the whole project gets republished.

To counter this, I'd have to manually hit every endpoint with a view in the project once. When the project first started this was a simple task but as you can imagine right now this is not maintainable.

My question is how do I execute a batch of curl commands to the endpoints with views in the project? I'm not sure where to start. Is there a programmatic way to create the batch command and append it to the AfterPublish event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you're encountering is due to Application Pool Start Mode in IIS. Instead of implementing AfterPublish events, you're probably better off  configuring your Application Pool to do what you want it to do.

> Start Mode
>
> A few web applications take a significant amount of time to start up. IIS by default only launches a worker process when the first request for the web application is received. So for the web applications that require a longer time to initialize, users might see slow responses.
>
> For such applications it is a good idea to launch the worker process as soon as IIS is started. The application pools have a startMode setting which when set to AlwaysRunning launches the worker process for the application pool as soon as IIS is started.
>
> IIS 8 provides you this setting in the Application Pool Settings UI.
>
> Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2012/10/09/iis-8-whats-new-application-pool-settings/

If you really want to run those actions after you publish the website, you'll have to learn more about the Visual Studio build process. This link can get you started: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-extend-the-visual-studio-build-process?view=vs-2017